# Regex word boundaries and distance between matches

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to be able to use a regular expression to find any matches for a particular keyphrase within some text.

The keyphrase may or may not contain 1 or more spaces (it would usually only be 1 word, but in some cases may be multiple words).

I am currently using the following expression where the keyphrase is a single word (containing no spaces):

```
var regexPattern = string.Format( "\\b({0})\\b", keyphrase );
```

When the keyphrase is multiple words (contains one or more spaces), I am then updating the expression to replace any of those spaces with a wildcard:

```
regexPattern = regexPattern.Replace( " ", ".*" );
```

There are a couple of scenarios where this is not behaving as I need it to.

1) If the keyphrase within my long text (that I'm searching for matches) is surrounded by either an underscore or a numeric, it no longer matches. It's fine with hyphens, commas, full stops etc. In those scenarios, it still detects the keyphrase in there, but I also need it to match when the keyphrase is surrounded with underscores or numerics.

2) In the scenario where my keyphrase consists of multiple words (contains 1 or more spaces), I would like to allow up to a certain maximum distance/length between each of the words that form my keyphrase.

e.g. If my keyphrase is:

```
for sale
```

... and the text that I am matching against is

```
I have a bike for    sale.
```

... (where there is up to a maximum distance of 5 characters between the keyphrase words), I would like the regex to match:

```
bike for    sale
```

However, if there was more distance between the keyphrase words than 5 characters, I would not want it to match.

Also, this 'distance' shouldn't be confined to the number of spaces that occur between the keyphrase words, as I would also like the following to match for example:

```
I have a bike for _.,1sale.
```

Finally, it's probably worth stating that in some cases, the keyphrase I'm searching for may appear more than once, and where the above conditions are met, I'd need both to be matched:

e.g.

```
I have a bike for _.,1sale. I've also got a laptop for sale!
```

So, I essentially have 2 additional requirements on what I currently have, but don't know regular expressions well enough to know how I can implement these.

Comment: The second problem is easily addressed with a limiting quantifier `.{1,5}` (from 1 up to 5 occurrences of any characters but a newline). But if a word boundary prevents from matching a keyword, just remove word boundaries, or use a smart method that will "know" where to add them and where not to. If you just want it to match between digits and `_`, you might want to check `string.Format( "(?<=\\P{L}|^)({0})(?=\\P{L}|$)", keyphrase )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following code to address 2 issues:

```
var regexPattern = string.Format( "(?<!\\p{{L}}){0}(?!\\p{{L}})", keyphrase );
// or
// var regexPattern = string.Format( "(?<=\\P{{L}}|^){0}(?=\\P{{L}}|$)", keyphrase );
regexPattern = regexPattern.Replace( " ", ".{0,5}" );
```

The regex will look like

```
(?<!\p{L})key.{0,5}word(?!\p{L})
```

or

```
(?<=\P{L}|^)key.{0,5}word(?=\P{L}|$)
```

Here is [demo 1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cP%7bL%7d%7c%5e)key.%7b0%2c5%7dword(%3f%3d%5cP%7bL%7d%7c%24)&i=_keyword_%0d%0a_key+word_%0d%0a_key++word_%0d%0a_key+*+word_%0d%0a2key+%25++word1%0d%0a4key+1++_word_5%0d%0akey++++++word) / [demo 2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5Cp%7BL%7D)key.%7B0%2C5%7Dword(%3F!%5Cp%7BL%7D)&i=_keyword_%0D%0A_key%20word_%0D%0A_key%20%20word_%0D%0A_key%20*%20word_%0D%0A2key%20%25%20%20word1%0D%0A4key%201%20%20_word_5%0D%0Akey%20%20%20%20%20%20word)

Mind that if you want to also match the inner word boundaries the same way, use

```
regexPattern = regexPattern.Replace( " ", "(?=\\P{L}).{0,5}(?<=\\P{L})" );
```

Regex will be

```
(?<!\p{L})key(?=\P{L}).{0,5}(?<=\P{L})word(?!\p{L})
```

or

```
(?<=\P{L}|^)key(?=\P{L}).{0,5}(?<=\P{L})word(?=\P{L}|$)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5CP%7BL%7D%7C%5E)key(%3F%3D%5CP%7BL%7D).%7B0%2C5%7D(%3F%3C%3D%5CP%7BL%7D)word(%3F%3D%5CP%7BL%7D%7C%24)&i=_keyword_%0D%0A_key%20word_%0D%0A_key%20%20word_%0D%0A_key%20*%20word_%0D%0A2key%20%25%20%20word1%0D%0A4key%201%20%20_word_5%0D%0Akey%20%20%20%20%20%20word), it will exclude the cases where the 2 words won't match if glued.

Comment: Perfect, the first example you've provided appears to work exactly as I need. Thanks for such a complete answer, and demos!

Comment: Just for completeness, I found that I needed to escape the curly braces for {L} in the string.Format line else it error'd, so it became: var regexPattern = string.Format( "(?<=\\P{{L}}|^){0}(?=\\P{{L}}|$)", keyphrase );

Comment: I think string concatenation is better in this case, since we avoid escaping `{` and `}`. Btw, `(?<=\P{L}|^)` is equivalent to `(?<!\p{L})`, and `(?=\P{L}|$)` is equivalent to `(?!\p{L})`

Comment: Initially, I had `(?<!\p{L})` and `(?!\p{L})`, but I wanted the pattern to be more explicit.